How can I re-enable my Steam Deck display in Desktop Mode?
I followed the instructions in this post to disable my Steam Deck's display when in Desktop Mode which is basically the following:

by going into settings > display configuration > device (laptop screen) > unchecked enabled & primary

But now my issue is: How do I re-enable it again? The display doesn't show up in the display configuration settings anymore. I see other people in that same post from above are also having the same issues where they don't know how to re-enable the display after disabling it.

This is what I see in my display settings:

I only see my two external displays. My Steam Deck's internal display isn't here anymore after I've disabled it. So I don't know where to find and enable it again.

How can I turn my Steam Deck's display on again when in desktop mode?

I found another solution:
Just simply select "Built-in Screen" option from the Device dropdown and click on the Enabled checkbox:


Okay, I managed to finally get my Steam Deck's display enabled again.
I opened the "Display Configuration" window from the system tray (bottom right):

And then I just clicked randomly on a couple of different options there, specifcally the "Extend to Left" and "Extend to Right" options:

And then suddenly my Steam Deck's built-in display turned on and worked again. So this seems to have enabled it again.
And now I can configure and see it between my other two monitors again as well:

